# Why this while condition don't break

Tags: bash

I am trying to wait my docker container is up to start some commands.

i am doing the following :

```
#!/bin/bash

DOCKER_IP=192.168.99.100
ES_PORT=9300

docker-compose up -d
while [ -z "$(nc -z $DOCKER_IP $ES_PORT)" ]; do
    sleep 1
done
echo "Do some stuff now it's up !"
```

I already check with `cat -e` the return of `nc -z` is empty, without the quotes, with `[ ! -n $(nc ...)]` as conditional expression ...

When the return of `nc` is not empty, i have `Connection to 192.168.99.100 port 9300 [tcp/vrace] succeeded!` in loop and it never exit.

Why this simple loop condition is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most probably because `nc` prints the message "`Connection to 192.168.99.100 port 9300 [tcp/vrace] succeeded!`" on the standard error rather than standard output (otherwise you shouldn't see it). You can redirect standard error (so that it is captured by the command substitution) as follows:

```
while [ -z "$(nc -z $DOCKER_IP $ES_PORT 2>&1)" ]; do
    sleep 1
done
```

However, not all versions of `nc` print such a message when connection succeeds (mine doesn't). So why don't you simply use the exit status of `nc -z`:

```
while ! nc -z $DOCKER_IP $ES_PORT
do
    sleep 1
done
```